# Creating a dictionary from a string

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a string in the form of:

```
s = 'A - 13, B - 14, C - 29, M - 99'
```

and so on (the length varies). What is the easiest way to create a dictionary from this?

```
A: 13, B: 14, C: 29 ...
```

I know I can split but I can't get the right syntax on how to do it. If I split on `-`, then how do I join the two parts?

Iterating over this seems to much of a pain.

Comment: I have a related question: What if my string looks like this: 'A-13-27', B-35-42' and I want a dictionary like this: A:(13,27), B:(35,42)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'A - 13, B - 14, C - 29, M - 99'
>>> dict(e.split(' - ') for e in s.split(','))
{'A': '13', 'C': '29', 'B': '14', 'M': '99'}
```

EDIT: The next solution is for when you want the values as integers, which I think is what you want.

```
>>> dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in (e.split(' - ') for e in s.split(',')))
{'A': 13, ' B': 14, ' M': 99, ' C': 29}
```

Comment: You can add `strip` to remove leading spaces: `dict( item.strip().split(' ') for item in clients.split(',') )`

Answer (score 27):

To solve your example you can do this:

```
mydict = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k,v in 
              (item.split('-') for item in s.split(',')))
```

It does 3 things:

- split the string into `"<key> - <value>"` parts: `s.split(',')`
- split each part into `"<key> ", " <value>"` pairs: `item.split('-')`
- remove the whitespace from each pair: `(k.strip(), v.strip())`

Comment: Woah, I feel really stupid right now. This *never* occurred to me.

Answer (score 14):

Those who came here with following problem :

convert string `a = '{"a":1,"b":2}'` to dictionary object.

you can simply use `a = eval(a)` to get `a` as object of dictionary from a string object.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> dict((k.strip(),int(v.strip())) for k,v in (p.split('-') for p in s.split(',')))
{'A': 13, 'B': 14, 'M': 99, 'C': 29}
```

Comment: +1 For thinking about turning the numbers into integers. Although I'd be tempted to break it up into two steps to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict((p.split(' - ') for p in s.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that doesn't use generator expressions and uses `replace` rather than `strip`.

```
>>> s = 'A - 13, B - 14, C - 29, M - 99'
>>> d = {}
>>> for pair in s.replace(' ','').split(','):
...     k, v = pair.split('-')
...     d[k] = int(v)
...
>>> d
{'A': 13, 'C': 29, 'B': 14, 'M': 99}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dict(map(lambda l:map(lambda j:j.strip(),l), map(lambda i: i.split('-'), s.split(','))))
```

If you don't want to strip, just do:

```
dict(map(lambda i: i.split('-'), s.split(',')))
```

Comment: Ah! My solutions don't convert integers!

Answer (score 0):

try regular expression findall. ignore whitespace, A-Z single white space then literal - then white space single then number

```
s = 'A - 13, B - 14, C - 29, M - 99'

result=re.findall('\s*([A-Z\s+\-0-9]+)',s)
dict={}
for item in result:
   key,value =item.split(' - ')
   dict[key]=value

print(dict)
```

output:

```
{'A': '13', 'B': '14', 'C': '29', 'M': '99'}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the variables that you create, including ones used by python itself are stored in `vars()` and `globals().`
I've used them before for creating variables on the fly in my code without having to previously assign `None` to a variable.

```py
dict_name: dict

if 'dict_name' not in vars():
    vars()['dict_name'] = {}

print(dict_name)
# output >> {}

if 'dict_name' not in globals():
    globals()['dict_name'] = {}

print(dict_name)
# output >> {}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).