# Is there a simpler way to build a dictionary from strings and then vectorize the strings? Python

Tags: python, dictionary, vector, nlp

My question on how to build a dictionary from string is a little more linguistically / NLP inclined than [Creating a dictionary from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627981/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-string)

Given a list of string sentences, **is there a simpler way to build a unique word dictionary and then vectorize the string sentences?** I know that there are external libraries to do this like `gensim` but i would like to avoid them. I've been doing it this way:

```
from itertools import chain

def getKey(dic, value):
  return [k for k,v in sorted(dic.items()) if v == value]

# Vectorize will return a list of tuples and each tuple is made up of 
# (<position of word in dictionar>,<number of times it occurs in sentence>)
def vectorize(sentence, dictionary): # is there simpler way to do this?
  vector = []
  for word in sentence.split():
    word_count = sentence.lower().split().count(word)
    dic_pos = getKey(dictionary, word)[0]
    vector.append((dic_pos,word_count))
  return vector

s1 = "this is is a foo"
s2 = "this is a a bar"
s3 = "that 's a foobar"

uniq = list(set(chain(" ".join([s1,s2,s3]).split()))) # is there simpler way for this?
dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(uniq)): # can this be done with dict(list_comprehension)?
  dictionary[i] = uniq[i]

v1 = vectorize(s1, dictionary)
v2 = vectorize(s2, dictionary)
v3 = vectorize(s3, dictionary)

print v1
print v2
print v3
```

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is, but I can tell you the following concerns: you make a **set** that you turn into a **list** which you then turn into a **dictionary** and proceed to look up **values** from the **dictionary** rather than the **keys** and they're all positional results from a **list** that you build **for every query!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
from itertools import chain, count

s1 = "this is is a foo"
s2 = "this is a a bar"
s3 = "that 's a foobar"

# convert each sentence into a list of words, because the lists
# will be used twice, to build the dictionary and to vectorize
w1, w2, w3 = all_ws = [s.split() for s in [s1, s2, s3]]

# chain the lists and turn into a set, and then a list, of unique words
index_to_word = list(set(chain(*all_ws)))

# build the inverse mapping of index_to_word, by pairing it with a counter
word_to_index = dict(zip(index_to_word, count()))

# create the vectors of word indices and of word count for each sentence
v1 = [(word_to_index[word], w1.count(word)) for word in w1]
v2 = [(word_to_index[word], w2.count(word)) for word in w2]
v3 = [(word_to_index[word], w3.count(word)) for word in w3]

print v1
print v2
print v3
```

Things to keep in mind:

- a dictionary should only be travelled from key to value; if you need to do the opposite, create (and keep updated) two dictionaries, one the inverse mapping of the other, as I do above;
- if you need a dictionary whose keys are consecutive integers, just use a list (thanks Jeff);
- never compute the same thing twice! (see the split() version of a sentence) save it in a variable if you need it later;
- use list comprehensions whenever you can, for performance, brevity and readability.

Comment: +1 for some great pythonic demonstrations of set and dict building.

Comment: index_to_word should be a list since we know they're all positional. Better memory and lookup time, same syntax to lookup.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to count number of occurrence of a word in a sentence, use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

problems with your code:

```
uniq = list(set(chain(" ".join([s1,s2,s3]).split()))) # is there simpler way for this?
dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(uniq)): # can this be done with dict(list_comprehension)?
  dictionary[i] = uniq[i]
```

what above part does is just creating a dictionary that is indexed by some arbitrary number (which came from iterating a `set` that has no concept of indices). then the above dictionary is accessed using

```
def getKey(dic, value):
  return [k for k,v in sorted(dic.items()) if v == value]
```

this function, which also totally ignores the spirit of dict : **you do lookups by keys, not values.**

also, the idea of `vectorize` is unclear. what do you seek to achieve by this function? you asked for a simpler version of `vectorize`, without telling us what it does.

Answer (score 1):

You've got multiple questions in your code, so let's answer them one by one.

---

```
uniq = list(set(chain(" ".join([s1,s2,s3]).split()))) # is there simpler way for this?
```

For one thing, it might be conceptually simpler (although just as verbose) to `split()` the strings independently, instead of joining them together then splitting the result.

```
uniq = list(set(chain(*map(str.split, (s1, s2, s3))))
```

Beyond that: it looks like you're always using the word lists, not the actual sentences, so you're splitting in multiple places. Why not just split them all at once, up at the top?

Meanwhile, instead of having to explicitly pass around `s1`, `s2`, and `s3`, why not stick them in a collection? And you can stick the results in a collection as well.

So:

```
sentences = (s1, s2, s3)
wordlists = [sentence.split() for sentence in sentences]

uniq = list(set(chain.from_iterable(wordlists)))

# ...

vectors = [vectorize(sentence, dictionary) for sentence in sentences]
for vector in vectors:
    print vector
```

---

```
dictionary = {}
for i in range(len(uniq)): # can this be done with dict(list_comprehension)?
  dictionary[i] = uniq[i]
```

You could do it as `dict()` on a list comprehension—but, even more simply, use a dict comprehension. And, while you're at it, use `enumerate` instead of the `for i in range(len(uniq))` bit.

```
dictionary = {idx: word for (idx, word) in enumerate(uniq)}
```

That replaces the whole `# ...` part in the above.

---

Meanwhile, if you want a reverse dictionary lookup, this is not the way to do it:

```
def getKey(dic, value):
    return [k for k,v in sorted(dic.items()) if v == value]
```

Instead, create an inverse dictionary, mapping values to lists of keys.

```
def invert_dict(dic):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in dic.items():
        d[v].append(k)
    return d
```

Then, instead of your `getKey` function, just do a normal lookup in the inverted dict.

If you need to alternate modifications and lookups, you probably want some kind of bidirectional dictionary, that manages its own inverse dictionary as it goes along. There are a bunch of recipes for such a thing on ActiveState, and there may be some modules on PyPI, but it's not that hard to build yourself. And at any rate, you don't seem to need that here.

---

Finally, there's your `vectorize` function.

The first thing to do is to take a word list instead of a sentence to split, as mentioned above.

And there's no reason to re-split the sentence after `lower`; just use a map or generator expression on the word list.

In fact, I'm not sure why you're doing `lower` here, when your dictionary is built out of the original-case versions. I'm guessing that's a bug, and you wanted to do `lower` when building the dictionary as well. That's one of the advantages of making the word lists in advance in a single, easy-to-find place: you just need to change that one line:

```
wordlists = [sentence.lower().split() for sentence in sentences]
```

Now you're already a bit simpler:

```
def vectorize(wordlist, dictionary):
    vector = []
    for word in wordlist:
        word_count = wordlist.count(word)
        dic_pos = getKey(dictionary, word)[0]
        vector.append((dic_pos,word_count))
    return vector
```

Meanwhile, you may recognize that the `vector = []… for word in wordlist… vector.append` is exactly what a list comprehension is for. But how do you turn three lines of code into a list comprehension? Easy: refactor it into a function. So:

```
def vectorize(wordlist, dictionary):
    def vectorize_word(word):
        word_count = wordlist.count(word)
        dic_pos = getKey(dictionary, word)[0]
        return (dic_pos,word_count)
    return [vectorize_word(word) for word in wordlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it looks like you want:

- A dictionary that returns a positional value for each token.
- A count of how many times a token is found in a set.

You could:

```
import bisect

uniq.sort() #Sort it since order didn't seem to matter

def getPosition(value):
    position = bisect.bisect_left(uniq, value) #Do a log(n) query
    if uniq[position] != value:
        raise IndexError
```

To search in O(n) time, you could instead create you set and iteratively insert each value with a sequential key. This is much less efficient on memory, but it provides O(n) search by a hash... and Tobia posted a great example of code while I was writing, so see that answer.