# Python Trivia Game and reading from files

Tags: python, oop

```
class Question(object):
def __init__(self, question, options, answer, description, points):
    self.question = question
    self.options = options
    self.answer = answer
    self.description = description
    self.points = points

def ask():
    response = None
    while response not in ("1", "2", "3", "4"):
        response = raw_input(self.question).lower()

    if response == self.answer:
        print "right"

    else:
        print "wrong"
```

questions = ?
answer = ?

I want it to go through the amount of questions I have but I want to add the question and other values from a text file.

That's what I have so far but I'm really confused on how to add the questions, answers, category, and point values from the same text file..

text file example trivia.txt:

```
Category
Question
Choice 1
Choice 2
Choice 3
Choice 4
Answer (being a digit 1-4)
Description why it is that answer
Point Value
```

Comment: There's a number of ways to do this but you'd have to make a design/implementation decision.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I could do that?

Comment: In regards to putting the questions one one line you could do something like this: 

Category|Question|Choice 1|Choice 2|Choice 3|Choice 4|Answer|Description|Point Value

Then use line.split('|')

Answer (score 0):

semi colon delimited i.e.

```
Category:Question:Choice 1:Choice 2:Choice 3:Choice 4:etc
```

The read them in and pass them to your object:

```
with open('questions.txt', 'r') as testfile:
    for line in testfile:
        question = (line.split(':'))
```

You know have an iterable list that you can use to assign values to the question. This is only one possible solution.

You can also look at the dictionary route:

[Creating a dictionary from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627981/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-string)