# Python String to dict while separator is '='

Tags: python

Hy i have a list of strings which look like:

```
atr = ['ID=cbs7435_mt', 'Name=cbs7435_mt', 'Dbxref=taxon:981350', 'Note=Pichia pastoris CBS 7435 mitochondrion%2C complete replicon sequence.', 'date=27-FEB-2015', 'mol_type=genomic DNA', 'organelle=mitochondrion', 'organism=Komagataella pastoris CBS 7435', 'strain=CBS 7435']
```

Now i want to create a dictionary which should look like:

```
my_dict = {'ID': 'cbs7435_mt', 'Name':'cbs7435_mt', ...}
```

Do someone has any advice how i could manage this?
Thanks already!

Comment: this is very simple, split your problem, and google it

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There are plenty of very similar questions on SO, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186857/splitting-a-semicolon-separated-string-to-a-dictionary-in-python) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627981/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` method of string to get Key and value for dictionary item.

Use `for` loop to iterate on given list input.

**Demo**:

```
>>> atr = ['ID=cbs7435_mt', 'Name=cbs7435_mt', 'Dbxref=taxon:981350']>>> result_dict = {}
>>> for item in atr:
...     key, value = item.split("=")
...     result_dict[key] = value
... 
>>> result_dict
{'Dbxref': 'taxon:981350', 'ID': 'cbs7435_mt', 'Name': 'cbs7435_mt'}
>>>
```

Comment: You have a typo in the 1st line of your answer: `spit()` instead of `split()`.

Comment: @MarianD: yes, Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Simply split it with `=` and use `dict()`

```
my_dict = dict(i.split('=') for i in atr)
```