# Convert string with [key]:[value] to dictionary

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to convert the following string(MULTI LINE) to dictionary in python3+:

```
props_str ="
[persist.sys.bootupvolume]: [0]
[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2]: [li]
[persist.sys.device_provisioned]: [1]
[persist.sys.displayinset.top]: [0]
[persist.sys.isolated_storage]: [true]
[persist.sys.locale]: [en-US]
[persist.sys.phonelock.mode]: [0]
[persist.sys.sf.color_saturation]: [1.0]
[persist.sys.sf.native_mode]: [1]
[persist.sys.timezone]: []"
```

Currently I'm using regular expression to convert above expression into a list, then convert the list to dictionary.

```
c = compile(r"\[(.*?)\]")
props_list = c.findall(props_str)

it = iter(props_list)
prop_dict = dict(zip(it, it))
```

With this method, sometimes I miss some key:value. I'm looking for an easier way to convert that.

Let's assume that our string has one line break between one [key]: \n [value]

```
props_str ="\
[persist.sys.bootupvolume]: [0]\
[persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2]: [li]\
[persist.sys.device_provisioned]: [1]\
[persist.sys.displayinset.top]: [0]\
[persist.sys.isolated_storage]: [true]\
[persist.sys.locale]: \
[en-US]\
[persist.sys.phonelock.mode]: [0]\
[persist.sys.sf.color_saturation]: [1.0]\
[persist.sys.sf.native_mode]: [1]\
[persist.sys.timezone]: []\
[persist.sys.boot.reason]: []\
[persist.sys.boot.reason.history]: [reboot,hardware_reset,4831146 \
reboot,ota,1586292448 \
bootloader,4766793  \
reboot,4766775]"
```

Output will be:

```
{
   'persist.sys.bootupvolume': '0',
   'persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2': 'li', 
   'persist.sys.device_provisioned': '1', 
   'persist.sys.displayinset.top': '0', 
   'persist.sys.isolated_storage': 'true', 
   'persist.sys.locale': 'en-US', 
   'persist.sys.phonelock.mode': '0', 
   'persist.sys.sf.color_saturation': '1.0', 
   'persist.sys.sf.native_mode': '1', 
   'persist.sys.timezone': ''
}
```

Notice: It will be missing 'persist.sys.boot.reason.history' propertie because of the multiple \n between same key:value. Also persist.sys.boot.reason was also not converted. Not sure why.

Comment: Show code, show cases that go wrong.

Comment: Regex is not necessarily a good hammer for this nail.

Comment: Your provided code shows no failure with the provided data sample. By the way, better avoid using `from re import compile`, and rather stick to `import re` then use `re.compile()`. Indeed, `compile` is already a Python built-in function.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I'm looking for a better solution. If you think there is a better way to do that, please let me known.

Comment: @Arnaud, Indeed, compile is a python built-in function. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should post a meaningful question first. Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and attempt to follow the instructions. The comments here are useful too.

Comment: Without failure cases, there's no way one can come up with better solutions, as they are dependent on your input data.

Comment: Just added a failure case. Please assume that it's a multi line string.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, added case with wrong output. Any ideia?

Comment: I've voted to reopen. Could you format the output dictionary with one entry per line, so it's legible? Also, please remove the "edit" heading and simply write a complete question.

Comment: There is a [`re.S == re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag. You are probably looking for that. It matches newlines with `.`. I'll post an answer as soon as this is reopened.

Comment: If you are willing, you can speed things up by deleting this question, and asking a new one, which is complete and follows site rules. Make sure it's not a direct copy-and-paste, because that will get flagged.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Done editing! Tanks for the replay!

Comment: The question still closed :/

Comment: Yes. Two more people have to vote to reopen. That's why I recommended deleting and reposting, but at this point that would be a bad idea. We'll have to wait.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Would you consider reverting your close vote now? OP has made this into a pretty clear question, and I would like to answer it.

Comment: @blhsing Would you consider reverting your close vote now? OP has made this into a pretty clear question, and I would like to answer it.

Comment: `props_dict = eval(props_str)` should do it. @bottega

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one-liner should do it.

```
prop_dict = dict((k[1: -1], v[1: -1]) for k, v in (item.split(': ') for item in props_str.split('\n')[1:]))
```

This assumes that there is a line break between each key-value pair.

It also assumes that the first line doesn't start with a key-value pair. If it does, just replace `props_str.split('\n')[1:]` with `props_str.split('\n')`.

Approach above is similar to the one taken in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628007/10155936).